# Polymorphic variants and let%bind type error

Tags: ocaml, polymorphic-variants

I'm trying to use the technique in [Composable Error Handling in OCaml](http://keleshev.com/composable-error-handling-in-ocaml) (Result type with polymorphic variants for errors) for some code I've written. The types of the functions I'm trying to use look like this:

```ml
val parse : parser -> token list -> (Nominal.term, [> `ParseError of string ]) Result.t
val lex : lexer -> string -> (token list, [> `LexError of string ]) Result.t
```

My attempt at composing them is this:

```ml
let lex_and_parse
  : parser -> lexer -> string -> (Nominal.term, [> `ParseError of string | `LexError of string ]) Result.t
  = fun parser lexer input ->
    let open Result.Let_syntax in
    let%bind tokens = lex lexer input in
    parse parser tokens
```

Unfortunately the compiler (4.09.0) reports a type error:

```
File "src/Pratt.ml", line 147, characters 4-23:
147 |     parse parser tokens
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Error: This expression has type
         (Nominal.term, [ `ParseError of string ]) result
       but an expression was expected of type
         (Nominal.term, [> `LexError of string ]) result
       The first variant type does not allow tag(s) `LexError
```

Note that if I do the equivalent by hand, the code compiles:

```ml
let lex_and_parse
  : parser -> lexer -> string -> (Nominal.term, [> `ParseError of string | `LexError of string ]) Result.t
  = fun parser lexer input ->
    match lex lexer input with
      | Error (`LexError err) -> Error (`LexError err)
      | Ok tokens ->
        (match parse parser tokens with
        | Ok result -> Ok result
        | Error (`ParseError err) -> Error (`ParseError err))
```

Actually, that's not quite true. The equivalent is this, which also fails to compile (in the same way):

```ml
    match lex lexer input with
      | Error err -> Error err
      | Ok tokens ->
        match parse parser tokens with
        | Ok result -> Ok result
        | Error err -> Error err
```

```
File "src/Pratt.ml", line 155, characters 29-32:
155 |         | Error err -> Error err
                                   ^^^
Error: This expression has type [ `ParseError of string ]
       but an expression was expected of type
         [> `LexError of string | `ParseError of string ]
       The first variant type does not allow tag(s) `LexError
```

So my question is this. Note that the error message says "This expression has type `` (Nominal.term, [ `ParseError of string ]) result ``". This is what I don't understand -- I never specify that type anywhere, in fact, both places `ParseError` is mentioned, it's with a `>` constraint. So where does this type come from? IE where does `[>`ParseError of string ]`become`[ `ParseError of string ]`?

Also:

- What's the difference between my attempt and Vladimir's original (which I assume compiles)?
- Is there a way to weaken a polymorphic variant from `[ x ]` to `[> x ]`? (other than mapping all the tags by hand from the first type to the second)

Edit:

I [uploaded all of my code](https://github.com/joelburget/lvca/blob/40f564283aaeefeebda5efde984e1f19e6f7345b/src/Pratt.ml#L114) for context.

Edit 2 (sorry):

I did some exploration and came up with this implementation:

```ml
let parse : parser -> token list -> (Nominal.term, [> `ParseError of string ]) Result.t
  = fun parser toks ->
    match expression parser toks with
    (* | [], result -> result *)
    (* | _, Error err -> Error err *)
    | _, Ok _ -> Error (`ParseError "leftover tokens")
    | _, _ -> Error (`ParseError "unimplemented")
```

If I remove *either* of the commented lines, the implementation of `lex_and_parse` starts to fail again. It's a bit disturbing to me that `parse` compiles and its type signature never changes, yet a caller can fail to typecheck. How is this possible? This kind of nonlocal effect seriously violates my expectation for how type checking / signatures (ought to) work. I'd really like to understand what's happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So first of all, your intuition is right, your code shall work, e.g., the following code is accepted by 4.09.0 without any type errors:

```
open Base

module type S = sig
  type parser
  type lexer
  type token
  type term

  val parse : parser -> token list -> (term, [> `ParseError of string ]) Result.t
  val lex : lexer -> string -> (token list, [> `LexError of string ]) Result.t
end

module Test (P : S) = struct
  open P
  let lex_and_parse :
    parser -> lexer -> string -> (term, [> `ParseError of string | `LexError of string ]) Result.t
    = fun parser lexer input ->
      let open Result.Let_syntax in
      let%bind tokens = lex lexer input in
      parse parser tokens
end


module PL : S = struct
  type parser
  type lexer
  type token
  type term

  let parse _parser _tokens = Error (`ParseError "not implemented")
  let lex _ _ = Error (`LexError "not implemented")
end
```

> So my question is this. Note that the error message says "This expression has type (Nominal.term, [ `ParseError of string ]) result". This is what I don't understand -- I never specify that type anywhere, in fact, both places ParseError is mentioned, it's with a > constraint. So where does this type come from? IE where does [>ParseError of string ]become[ ParseError of string ]?

You are right, this is the main culprit. For some reason, your `parse` function returns a value of type

```
(term, [`ParseError of string])
```

where the type of the error constituent is a ground type, i.e., it is not polymorphic and cannot be extended. It is hard to tell, why this has happened, but I bet that there should be some type annotation that you have put that stops the type checker from inferring the most general type for the `parse` function. In any case, the culprit is hiding somewhere and is not in the code that you have shown us.

> Is there a way to weaken a polymorphic variant from [ x ] to [> x ]? (other than mapping all the tags by hand from the first type to the second)

Yes,

```
# let weaken x = (x : [`T]  :> [> `T]);;
val weaken : [ `T ] -> [> `T ] = <fun>
```

> What's the difference between my attempt and Vladimir's original (which I assume compiles)?

Your parse function in fact returns a non-extensible type. Note that to turn an non-extensible type to extensible, you have to use the full form coercion, e.g., if you will define `lex_and_parse` as

```
  let lex_and_parse :
    parser -> lexer -> string -> (term, [> `ParseError of string | `LexError of string ]) Result.t
    = fun parser lexer input ->
      let open Result.Let_syntax in
      let parse = (parse
                   :  _ -> _ -> (_, [ `ParseError of string]) Result.t
                   :> _ -> _ -> (_, [> `ParseError of string]) Result.t) in

      let%bind tokens = lex lexer input in
      parse parser tokens
```

it will compile. But again the main culprit is the type of your `parse` function.

### Where the actual bug was hiding

After OP have uploaded the source code we were able to identify why and where the OCaml typechecker was denied from inferring the general and polymorphic type.

Here is the story, the `parse` function is implemented as

```
let parse : parser -> token list -> (Nominal.term, [> `ParseError of string ]) Result.t
  = fun parser toks -> match expression parser toks with
    | [], result -> result
    | _, Ok _ -> Error (`ParseError "leftover tokens")
    | _, Error err -> Error err
```

So its return type is a unification of the types of the folowing expressions:

- `result`,
- `Error ('ParseError "leftover tokens")`
- `Error err`

in addition we have a *type constraint*

```
parser -> token list -> (Nominal.term, [> `ParseError of string ]) Result.t
```

And here is an important thing to understand, a type constrained is not a definition, so when you say `let x : 'a = 42` you are not defining `x` to have a universal polymorphic type `'a`. A type constraint `(expr : typeexpr)` *forces the type of `expr` to be compatible with `typexpr`*. In other words, type constraint can only *constrain* the type, but the type itself is always inferred by the type checker. If the inferred type is more general, e.g., `'a list` than the constraint, e.g., `int list`, then it will be constrained to `int list`. But you can't move the other way around as it will defeat the type soundness, e.g., if the inferred type is `int list` and your constraint is `'a list`, then it will still be `'a list` (treat it like intersection of types).  Again, the type inference will infer the most general type, and you can only make it less general.

So, finally, the return type of the `parse` subroutine is the result of unification of the three expressions above plus the user constraint. The type of `result` is the smallest type, since you have constrained the `expression` function [here](https://github.com/joelburget/lvca/blob/40f564283aaeefeebda5efde984e1f19e6f7345b/src/Pratt.ml#L69) to return errors of the non-extensible ground type [parse_error](https://github.com/joelburget/lvca/blob/40f564283aaeefeebda5efde984e1f19e6f7345b/src/Pratt.ml#L32).

Now to mitigations.

The easiest solution is to remove type annotations at all and rely on the type checker, merlin, and well-defined interfaces (signatures) when you program. Indeed, the type annotation only confused you here. You wrote an extensible `[> ...]` type annotation and believed that the inferred type is extensible which wasn't true.

If you need to keep them or if you need to make the expression function a part of your interface, then you have two options, either make your `parse_error` extensible, and this means polymorphic or use type coercion to weaken the type of result and make it extensible, e.g.,

```
| [], result -> (result : parse_error :> [> parse_error])
```

If you will decide to make your `parse_error` type extensible, you can't just say

```
type parse_error = [> `ParseError of string]
```

because now parse_error denotes a whole family of types, so we need to represent this variability of type with a type variable, two syntaxes here are applicable,

```
type 'a parse_error = [>
  | `ParseError of string
  | `MoonPhaseError of int
] as 'a
```

or a more verbose, but to my taste more precise,

```
type 'a parse_error = 'a constraint 'a = [>
    | `ParseError of string
    | `MoonPhaseError of int
  ]
```

Both definitions are equivalent. The all mean that type `'a parser_error` is a type variable `'a` s.t. `'a` includes the ParseError, the MoonPhaseError and infinitely more errors of unspecified genera.

Comment: Hi ivg, thanks so much for the great answer. I learned a lot from what you have here, but wasn't quite able to figure out why my parse function has the wrong type. I uploaded what I have [here](https://github.com/joelburget/lvca/blob/40f564283aaeefeebda5efde984e1f19e6f7345b/src/Pratt.ml#L114) if you're able to take a look.

Comment: As I was predicting, you indeed manually constrained the type, I will update the post with the details, but here it is https://github.com/joelburget/lvca/blob/40f564283aaeefeebda5efde984e1f19e6f7345b/src/Pratt.ml#L32

Answer (score 2):

The following functorized code:

```
module F(X: sig
    type parser type lexer type token
    module Nominal: sig type term end
    val parse :
      parser -> token list -> (Nominal.term, [> `ParseError of string ]) Result.t
    val lex : lexer -> string -> (token list, [> `LexError of string ]) Result.t
end) = struct
open X

let (let*) x f = match x with
  | Error _ as e -> e
  | Ok x -> f x

let lex_and_parse parser lexer input =
  let* tokens = lex lexer input in
  parse parser tokens
end
```

compiles just fine with the expected type for `lex_and_parse`.

The issue is thus probably that your implementation of `parse` and `lex` have a closed error type.

Note that this issue could be fixed easily with a coercion since the closed error type is a subtype of the open one:

```
let fix parse =
(parse:
    parser -> token list -> (Nominal.term, [`ParseError of string ]) Result.t
 :> parser -> token list -> (Nominal.term, [>`ParseError of string ]) Result.t
 )
```

but it is probably better to fix the implementation of the corresponding functions.

EDIT:

The initial error comes from this part of your code:

```ml
type parse_error = [ `ParseError of string ]
type parse_result = (Nominal.term, parse_error) Result.t
...
let rec expression
  : parser -> ?rbp:int -> token list -> token list * parse_result
...
let parse :
  parser -> token list -> (Nominal.term, [> `ParseError of string ]) Result.t
  = fun parser toks -> match expression parser toks with
    | [], result -> result
```

Here your are constraining the error in the `parse_error` type to be exactly `` `Parse_error ``. Thus, when you return `result` in `parse`, its type its `(_,parse_error) result`. And since this result type can be unified with your annotation, no error is raised.

Maybe a first fix is to detail the type to make the typechecker aware that you intended the error type to be open:

```ml
let parse : 'error.
  parser -> token list -> 
  (Nominal.term, [> `ParseError of string ] as 'error) Result.t
  = fun parser toks -> match expression parser toks with
    | [], result -> result
```

Here, the explicit universal annotation on the return type will prevent the type to be closed behind your back (the error message might be confusing before 4.10 ).

Then, one possible fix is to add a coercion to reopen the error type in parse:

```ml
let parse : 'error.
  parser -> token list ->
  (Nominal.term, [> `ParseError of string ] as 'error) Result.t
  = fun parser toks -> match expression parser toks with
    | [], result -> (result:>(Nominal.term, [> parse_error]) result)
```

or you could make the error type of expression open too:

```ml
type parse_error = [ `ParseError of string ]
type 'a parse_result = (Nominal.term, [> parse_error] as 'a) Result.t
...
let rec expression
  : parser -> ?rbp:int -> token list -> token list * 'a parse_result
  = ...
```

Or an even easier fix: remove the type annotation, with

```
let rec expression parser ... =
```

without the type annotation, the compiler inferq the right type. Indeed, this is a quite generic situation: the compiler is guaranteed to infer the best possible type without user interference.

Comment: Hi octachron, I uploaded all of my code [here](https://github.com/joelburget/lvca/blob/40f564283aaeefeebda5efde984e1f19e6f7345b/src/Pratt.ml#L114) to help give context, since it still seems to me the types of lex and parse are correct.

Comment: I have edited my answer to explain the original error.

Comment: Thanks octachron. I'm still a bit puzzled and created a smaller test case explaining why in https://stackoverflow.com/q/62175970/383958.